# Google Sheets script: return value if substring is within another column

Tags: javascript, excel, search, google-sheets

I'm new (read: literally just looking at JS for the first time now) to Javascript/Sheets/scripts in general, so forgive me for how basic this is. I've done a lot of independent research with no luck.

I have a spreadsheet with a column for full name (all caps - LAST, FIRST format), split into two additional columns of LAST and FIRST (full name split via comma), and then a lower caps column that contains the full name of the person in First Last format.

There are some errors in the data - for instance, LAST, FIRST might be followed by First Last that is a totally different name, or an incorrect spelling of the prior column. I'm basically trying to flag it when there is a mismatch in the contents, either spelling-wise or the name overall.

I've written this simple script that pulls the first name (column D) and the full name in First Last format (column F) and checks whether the first name is contained in the full name. Supposedly, it should return the value of search() in column G. That way I can use conditional formatting to flag any #VALUE! that appears from a failed search, indicating that the row needs to be checked.

Unfortunately the script runs infinitely and I can't figure out why I'm unable to hit a break point and actually return values in the corresponding columns in the actual sheet. This is a tiny project and I am struggling to justify learning the interface between scripts and Sheets from scratch, so I would really appreciate some help! Thank you!

```
   function checkName() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
      var data_len = data.length;
      for(var i=6; i<data_len; i++) {
        var fname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        var fullname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        s.getRange(i, 7).setValue(fullname.includes(fname));    
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know for sure that it runs infinitely? Also, logs are a dev's best friend :-) Sheets / Google Apps Script provides a couple of ways of logging, and the easiest to use for debugging is the [Apps Script execution log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#use_the_apps_script_execution_log)

Comment: Thanks @somewhatsapient! It times out after 6 minutes and there are only 5225 rows in the sheet, so I'd imagine that it's looping somewhere. On debug it never hits a breakpoint, and the execution log is completely empty except to mark that it's starting and ending. So I have no leads at all, which is frustrating.

Comment: Unless there's more to your code than what you're showing here, you haven't set any breakpoints nor included any logging statements. I would suggest adding a breakpoint after your last line inside the for loop, and maybe create a variable to store the results of the `.setValue()` operation, then log `fname`, `fullname`, and that variable. That way you can peek under the hood a bit.

Comment: I realize now that the Apps Script environment does let you set breakpoints in the UI - what I was referring to was the use of `debugger` statements in the code.

Comment: @somewhatsapient I think it's working now, for some reason that break point was all it needed to update the sheet too?? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @somewhatsapient Really quick, for some reason it always times out after 1000 or so lines and is super slow. Any idea as to why?

Comment: You can replace those references to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` inside the `for` loop with `s` since you've already assigned that value to `s`. Not sure how much overhead there is performance-wise with those methods, but it can't hurt.

Comment: But also, you have the data as an array already - why not get it there instead of dipping back into `getRange()`?

Comment: @somewhatsapient To be honest, I don't know how to (eee). Is it something as simple as s(i, 3).getValue()?

Comment: Since you set `s` equal to the value of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`, just replace `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` with `s`. Like `const firstName = s.getRange(i, 4).getValue()`. But it's still going to be slow since you're querying the spreadsheet with each iteration. You already have all values in the `data` array, so you should access that. I'll answer with an example.

Comment: @somewhatsapient Oh, yes, I did replace all of those with s, I'm just not sure exactly how to access the values in the data array syntax-wise (can you believe I actually have a bachelor's in CS? neither can I)

Comment: Every language and runtime and context is different! Quick question: why are you starting at `i=6` ?

Comment: @somewhatsapient The data on the sheet starts at row 6

Comment: What are you doing about case sensitivity? I'm not entirely clear on which column is which from your description, but it sounds like you're trying to compare an ALL-CAPS column with a column of mixed case. `.includes()` is case sensitive.

Comment: @somewhatsapient I changed that by just making the values .toLowerCase(). I haven't gotten any improvement in runtime, really, but this can be sloppy enough that I'm just plugging in the last row that it checks as i when it times out after 6 minutes. It does about 1000 rows at a time before collapsing lol. It's 100% accurate, just slow as anything.

Comment: Check out the answer I posted - even if you don't use it whole cloth, you might try at least removing all get/setValue calls from within your loop in favor of get/setValues calls before/after the loop. That's probably the biggest contributor to its sluggishness.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd write a function to meet your requirements:

```
function checkName() {

  // these two will be used in an Array,
  // which is 0-indexed
  const FIRST_NAME_COLUMN = 3; 
  const FULL_NAME_COLUMN = 5;

  // these two will be used in a Sheets range,
  // which is 1-indexed
  const INCLUDES_COLUMN = 7;
  const FIRST_ROW = 6;

  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetDataRange = s.getDataRange(); // this is just the whole shebang

  // get the dimensions of the main range
  const RANGE_HEIGHT = sheetDataRange.getHeight();
  const RANGE_WIDTH = sheetDataRange.getWidth();
  
  // use your first row number to constrain the actual data range
  // we'll use this reference to create an array we can easily iterate over
  const dataRange = s.getRange( FIRST_ROW, 1, RANGE_HEIGHT, RANGE_WIDTH );

  // data is a 2-dimensional Array,
  // so you could get values like data[row][column]
  // Also, Arrays are 0-indexed, so every number is 1 less than you had originally
  const data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  Logger.log( data ); // just to inspect

  const includesArray = [];

  for (const row of data) {
    // using a for ... of loop means we don't have to track the index,
    // and we can treat each row as a 1-D array inside the loop
    const firstName = row[FIRST_NAME_COLUMN];
    const fullName = row[FULL_NAME_COLUMN];
    const included = fullName.includes(firstName); // btw this will return a value of TRUE for ones that do include and FALSE for those that don't

    Logger.log( `${firstName}, ${fullName}, ${included}` );
    // debugger;
    includesArray.push( [included] ); // adding an Array that includes just the single element, since that represents a single data column
  }

  Logger.log( includesArray );
  debugger;

  s.getRange( FIRST_ROW, INCLUDES_COLUMN, RANGE_HEIGHT, 1 ).setValues( includesArray );

}
```

I'm using `const` when possible, for both scoping and to indicate that I won't be re-assigning the variables. I'm also assigning magic numbers to THESE_CONSTANTS so they have some semantic meaning in the code (that's just for my sanity).

Also, I'm not touching the "database" inside the loop at all - I'm strictly working with JS Arrays here. I've pulled the data from the Sheet with `dataRange.getValues()`, then I'm writing all the includes values to the Sheet at once after the loop with `setValues()`. This is where you're likely to see the best improvement in terms of performance.

Give it a shot, and ask any questions you need!

Comment: Thank you so so much! I'll check it out!!